Let F be a smooth projective curve over C. What about connectedness of V(F)
Let $F$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Then $V(F)$ is then a compact 1-dimensional complex manifold, and hence a compact $2$-dimensional real manifold. What about connectedness of $V(F)$?
In A. Gathmann notes on Plane Algebraic curve, page 38: About connectedness of V(F),  A. Gathmann use the follwing fact:
Fact: The notion of degree as well as Bézout’s Theorem can be extended to compact oriented 2-dimensional submanifolds of $P^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}$ (Can anyone give a reference of this fact?).

I'm not sure what Gathmann had in mind, but this might be somewhat more tricky. Surely $2$-dimensional compact oriented manifolds can intersect in infinitely many points, for example the intersection of two spheres in $\mathbb R^3$ can be a circle. You can then embed this into $P^2_{\mathbb C}$...

If two 2-dimensional compact oriented submanifolds in $P^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}$ always intersect, then we are done.

Is there any other kind of argument for connectedness?

Well, 2-dim real manifolds need not intersect in $P^2_{\mathbb C}$. You can take two disjoint spheres in my example. Note that $P^2_{\mathbb C}$ contains an open subset of the form $\mathbb C^2$, which itself contains $\mathbb R^3$ as a closed subspace. So everything you can do with compact submanifolds of $\mathbb R^3$ you can also realize in $P^2_{\mathbb C}$.

I took a look at Gathmann's notes, and he goes on to explain how homology can be used to get a result, in the following paragraphs. However, I'm not sure this is enough, since there might be connected component homologous to zero (like my spheres above).
